# How can UIColor be a type in Swift?

Tags: swift, class, types

I am learning Swift and this basic piece of code is confusing to me. Here is the code:

```
var newBackgroundColor : UIColor
```

I practiced with : Int or : String... Never this "custom" ones. My question is: is UIColor a class or a type? And if it is a class why don't we use this code:

```
var newBackgroundColor = UIColor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Cmd-click the `UIColor` in your code you will be brought to the header-file of UIKit framework, straight to `UIColor` public interface, where you can see that yes, it's a class.  Alternatively, you can look it up in Apple's documentation.

Reason why you can't do just

```
var newBackgroundColor = UIColor
```

... is that `=` is a shorthand for initialisation here.  You not only indicate the type of a property/variable but also specify its initial value.  I.e. for this to work you need to specify which exactly color should it be.  E.g.

```
var newBackgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Otherwise, if you really only need to declare the type, but initialisation will happen later, then you should use:

```
var newBackgroundColor : UIColor
```

Answer (score 2):

First, yes, `UIColor` is a class. It's part of UIKit. See [UIColor Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/index.html).

Second, you asked why you can't do:

```
var newBackgroundColor = UIColor
```

You can't do that because it's not syntactically correct. You can't just say `=` where the righthand expression is just the name of a class. It would have to be an instance of the class, e.g.:

```
var newBackgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

That defines a `UIColor` variable and initializes it with a particular instance. That's actually shorthand for:

```
var newBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIColor` is both a class and a type. All classes are types.

The declaration

```
var newBackgroundColor: UIColor
```

declares `newBackgroundColor` to hold a reference to an instance of class `UIColor`.